# What is function of closeContextMenu(), closeOptionsMenu(),etc.?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm just another android newbie, I am not understanding why there is a need for closeContextMenu() and closeOptionsMenu() before anything else is executed ...thanks in advance...

```
Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                closeContextMenu();
                closeOptionsMenu();
                progressBar=new MobiProgressBar(EncodeActivity.this);
                progressBar.setMax(100);
                progressBar.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.encoding));
                progressBar.show();
                Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Uri uri= encode();                      
                        MmsIntent mms=new MmsIntent(uri,EncodeActivity.this);
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                        mms.send();

                        //handler.post(mShowAlert);

                    }
                });
                tt.start();
```

Comment: please reconsider the question, I have edited it to make it more intelligible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find these methods in [the Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

[`closeContextMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#closeContextMenu%28%29):

> Programmatically closes the most recently opened context menu, if showing.

[`closeOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#closeOptionsMenu%28%29):

> Progammatically closes the options menu.

If you are confused about what the context and options menus are, check out [the Menus documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).